# How to add onClickListener to open barcode scanner?

Tags: barcode-scanner

I had write a code on trigger Barcode Scanner. I would like to trigger it after i clink on a button, but it doesn't work when i drop the code inside the onclicklistener. Need help on how to resolve this.

I had also include the button inside.

````
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv_isbn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_display);
        btn_camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
        btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                camera();
            }
        });
    }

    ```
````